# Include navigation properties of inherited entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework, eager loading and I'm trying to load a part of my graph.
I have Person table inherited by Candidate and Trainer, and I have a problem when someone is both, Trainer and Candidate (NOTE: Trainer and Candidate don't have any additional properties, only primary key inherited from Person).

This is my query:

```
RequestInfo ri = context.RequestInfo.Include(x => x.Request).Include(x => x.TeamName).Include(x => x.Sender)
                .Include(x => x.TrainingLanguage).Include(x => x.TrainingLocation).Include(x => x.CcPerson.Select(p => p.Person))
                .Include(x => x.Request.Select(c => c.Candidate))
                .Include(x => x.Request.Select(c => c.Candidate).Select(ct => ct.CandidateType))
                .Include(x => x.Request.Select(c => c.Candidate.CandidateType.Select(cwp => cwp.CandidateWorkPresence)))
                .Where(x => x.Id == r.Id).Single();
```

It probably might be better, but what I have as a problem is, when some person is Candidate and Trainer i get following exception:

```
All objects in the EntitySet 'EmployeesTrainingEntities.Person' must have unique primary keys. However, an instance of type 'EmployeesTrainingModel.Candidate' and an instance of type 'EmployeesTrainingModel.Trainer' both have the same primary key value, 'EntitySet=Person;PersonId=5'.
```

I try to find some solution for the problem, but i didn't have luck, and I saw that many people have this problem. Maybe I'm missing something, so if someone has some solution, suggestion,... it's welcome. 
If it's necessary I will add a photo that contains a part of my model which I'm trying to load.

**EDIT:**
Model contains `RequestInfo` entity which has common information about requests for training. `RequestInfo` has collection of `Requests`, `Sender` who is `Person` and collection of `CcPersons` (persons that will follow the training). `Request` contains `Candidate`.

**Solution:**
I found out solution of my problem. When I have person who is *Trainer* and *Candidate*, what I do is inheritance overlapping, and it seems that *EntityFramework* doesn't allow inheritance overlapping. So, I replaced inheritance relationship with association, and now it works properly.

Comment: Using inheritance for your model doesn't seem right. If a `Person` can be both a `Trainer` and a `Candidate` you can't derive those from `Person` because it would mean that a `Person` can only be **either** a `Trainer` **or** a `Candidate` but never both. Maybe you should have a base `Role` entity and derive `Trainer` and `Candidate` from `Role`. Then give `Person` a **collection** of `Role`s.

Comment: It could happen that some Person is both a `Trainer` and `Candidate`. I have Trainers for some course, but in my process it is possible that one of Trainers applies some other Trainer for training and it trainer will be candidate on a training. When something like that happen I cannot include information about Candidate in my Request because there is same `PersonId` in both tables `Candidate` and `Trainer`.

Comment: I edited the post with some additional explanation of a part of the model, because I cannot add a photo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in creating two extra entities that inherit from person if they dont have any additional properties.

Why not just edit the Person table, to include an enum [flag] property for `PersonRole`. That way you can assign multiple roles to one user and store them in an int.

Comment: I didn't do that because later it will be easier to add some new role if it is necessary or some additional property for teacher or Candidate, so it will be easier to extend a model. And even now these derived tables are associated with different tables.